# Counting total un-reply messages

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection named `comment` which contains user comment and it's designed structure is like this:

```
{
  "_id":ObjectId("53b76888e4b01917be0a7a76");
  "username":"Bob",
  "content":"That is very good for me :D",
  "threadId":"5c9597f3c8245907ea71a89d9d39d08e",
  "parent":""
}
```

There are a lot of comments in the collections, and reply to former comment will generate a new comment whose `parent` will be the former comment's `_id`, and they will be with the same `threadId`. And if the comment is a **init** comment of the thread(which means it's not replied to any former comments, *unReplied*) the `parent` field of the **init** comment will be mark as a empty string `""`.

- I can retrieve comments in aggregation of same `theadId` with
  mongodb's aggregation mechanism.
- I can even retrieve all *unReplied* thread, by grouping with
  `threadId` and make a `count` field and do another filter with the
  condition of `count==1` in pipelines and iterate with the cursor.

But now I want to know how many *unReplied* threads are there, iterating the above `cursor` won't be a good idea, I think. For I have to iterate through the whole cursor until there are no more records to know the total count of the *unReplied* threads. It's to expensive.

Is there a more elegant way to do this? Or is there a way of knowing the count of aggregation records without iterating the cursor through?

Comment: So what are you actually asking here? How to find all items in a collection that have not been "replied" to?

Comment: Yes, it's what I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic seems to be that the whole conversation uses the same "threadId", so an initial mesage creates that "threadId" with it's own `_id` value of course. Then each "child" in response quotes the `_id` of the comment preceeding it in the "parent" field and so on.

So put basically, every conversation is defined by its own "threadId" and an "unread" conversation has only "one" item which has no "parentId".

Then the aggregation logic here is:

1. Count how many messages in each thread
2. Discard the ones with a "count" more than 1
3. Count those distinct messages to obtain the un-read count

In a aggregagtion pipeline, you just implement those "three" same steps:

```js
 db.comment.aggregate([
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$threadId",
        "count": { "$sum": 1 }
    }},
    { "$match": { "count": { "$gt": 1 } } },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": null,
        "count": { "$sum": 1 }
    }}
])
```

So [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) on "threadId", [**`$match`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) to filter the counted results, then [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) again to obatin the count of those remaining.

Comment: Thanks @Blakes, That will give me what I want.